# How to adjust datagrid column

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, wpfdatagrid

I have `DataGrid` on WPF and connected with MS Access database. MS Access filled my `DataGrid`. How can I adjust my column width? For instance first column `widgh="2*"` , second column `widgh="*"`etc. Thank you!

Comment: Next time try and search your question on the internet first, if you did you should have ended up with the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the columns explictily in your XAML and set `AutoGenerateColumns` to `false`:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding Column1}" Width="1*" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="..." Binding="{Binding Column2}" Width="2*" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Or handle the `AutoGeneratingColumn` event:

```
private void DataGrid_AutoGeneratingColumn(object sender, DataGridAutoGeneratingColumnEventArgs e)
{
    //...
    e.Column.Width = new DataGridLength(1, DataGridLengthUnitType.Star);
}
```